# Initialize variable depending on another variables type

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 I want to intialize a variables type depending on another variable.

For example I want to do something like:

```
var_1 = type(var_2)
```

Is there a simple/fast way to do that?

Comment: How many different types are we talking about?  `isinstance()` is usually a better solution than `type()` (*usually*, not always).

Comment: Working on a function that takes an iterable  object as argument and defines a variable of the same type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create another instance

```
var_1 = type(var_2)()
```

Note that if you're not sure whether the object has a non-default constructor, you cannot rely on the above, but you can use `copy` or `deepcopy` (you get a "non-empty" object.

```
import copy
var_1 = copy.copy(var_2)  # or copy.deepcopy
```

You could use both combined with the latter as a fallback mechanism

Note: `deepcopy` will ensure that your second object is completely independent from the first (If there are lists of lists, for instance)

Comment: Thank you! One more question regarding the copy library. By reading the docs it seems like copy.deepcopy() is more suitable for this purpose, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 1              # a is an int
a_type = type(a)   # a_type now contains the int-type
b = '1'            # '1' is a string
c = a_type(b)      # c is now an int with the value 1
```

So you can get the type of a variable using `type()`. You can then store this type in a variable and you can then use that variable just like you would use `int(b)`, `str(b)`, `float(b)` etc.